# How to pass '\v\C[pattern]' into the built-in match() VimScript function

Tags: vimscript, regular-expression

I am attempting custom fold logic as my first VimScript.

What works for me: USING VERY MAGIC (\v) and explicit CASE SENSITIVE (\C), find python comments in foo.py that begin with hash, then Roman Numeral, a period, and finally .*$

```
"/\v\C^#(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})\.\s.*$.@<="
```

I want to apply this pattern to tell Vim when to start a fold in my Python scripts. The same pattern that works in foo.py now stops working once I pass it to a function. I assign the pattern to a variable in match() in python.vim:

```
function! PythonFolds()
  let thisline = getline(v:lnum)

  let rom_num = "\v\C^#(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})\.\s.*$.@<="
  if match(thisline, rom_num) >= 0
    return ">1"
  else
    return "=" 
  endif
endfunction

setlocal foldmethod=expr
setlocal foldexpr=PythonFolds()
setlocal foldcolumn=4
```

Basically when the above code is applied to a python.vim preference file, the folds are not applied. I have successfully tested simpler regex, which makes me believe the problem can be isolated as something I don't understand with regex/VimScript:

```
 if match(thisline, "^#") >= 0      " folds work as intended
   return ">1"
```

Additionally, the tutorials below suggest that \v and \C are both passable in VimScript.

- \v
  http://andrewradev.com/2011/05/08/vim-regexes/
- \C
  http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/46.html

I am running Vim8 on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Where did you put the file? Is folding enabled (`zi`)? Did you check the value of of the options you set (`setlocal foldmethod? foldexpr? foldcolumn?`)

Comment: Have you tried using single quotes around your pattern?

Comment: If you use double quotes, you need to double the backslashes, so use single quotes. See `:h expr-quote`

Comment: Single quotes worked, which means Vimscript indeed accepts \v and \C in pattern definitions. If there is a way to select comment as answer, please let me know.